# Probability and averages dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If you know the odds of something happening, say a particular set in a roll of 3 dice is 1/64 odds then how does one calculate the average number of rolls to produce this outcome?

Comment: You are asking for the expectation of a [geometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).